# Using FFmpeg without NDK in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

I go though many site and search regarding "**FFMPEG**" implementation for android project.

Most solution founded are using NDK.

but i want to use **FFmpeg without using NDK** as i found in **[This Link](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)**

Comment: It's possible to use FFMPEG executive file using Android's command line during runtime. What is your question exactly?

Comment: i want to use ffmpeg native library in my project ex. .so file

Comment: Please refer the link i have provided in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this project 
https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

It has already compiled for android version of FFMPEG library and this file will be in res/raw folder (you can update this file if you need newer version). You need to add this project as a library to your's. And after thst you can write your own function in java for example like this:

```
public Clip convert (Clip mediaIn, String outPath, ShellCallback sc) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

    cmd.add(mFfmpegBin);
    cmd.add("-y");
    cmd.add("-i");
    cmd.add(new File(mediaIn.path).getCanonicalPath());

    if (mediaIn.startTime != null)
    {
        cmd.add("-ss");
        cmd.add(mediaIn.startTime);
    }
    if (mediaIn.duration != -1)
    {
        cmd.add("-t");
        cmd.add(String.format(Locale.US,"%f",mediaIn.duration));

    }
    Clip mediaOut = new Clip();
    File fileOut = new File(outPath);
    mediaOut.path = fileOut.getCanonicalPath();
    cmd.add(mediaOut.path);
    execFFMPEG(cmd, sc);
    return mediaOut;
}
```

and execute it using FfmpegController Object.
Please notice me if you have any questions or if this is what you want.

**EDIT:**
I hope you connect this github code as a library for your project.
There is [FfmpegController.java](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/blob/master/src/org/ffmpeg/android/FfmpegController.java) class in src folder. It's a wrapper for using command line ffmpeg exe file. If you want for example execute command like this one

```
ffmpeg -i source.wav -b:a 128k output.mp3
```

you need to add function to FfmpegController.java class. Something like this:

```
    public Clip convert(Clip mediaIn, String outPath, ShellCallback sc) throws Exception
    {
    ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

    Clip mediaOut = new Clip();

    String mediaPath = mediaIn.path;

    cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

    cmd.add(mFfmpegBin);
    cmd.add("-i");
    cmd.add(mediaPath);

    cmd.add("-b:a");
    cmd.add("128k");

    mediaOut.path = outPath;

    cmd.add(mediaOut.path);

    execFFMPEG(cmd, sc);

    return mediaOut; // this is not importatnt because file will be put in outPath
    }
```

Now in your project initialize FfmpegController object and run your function.

Comment: i have implement it. unable to find execFFMPEG(cmd,sc) and cmd.add(mFfmpegBin);

Comment: one more question can use any ffmpeg commands using this lib? how?

Comment: Couldn't replay faster .Check my edit. Hope it is what you want

Comment: Thanks. can i use these library project in production environment(it is open source).i want to use this library in my google play application. can i?

Comment: Yes you can, but it's GPLv3 so if you use this library you must restrict your commercial app with GPLv3 too. So you are obligated to publish your sources. But I believe you are not using much from this library. It can be only a guidence of how to use FFmpeg library (which is under LGPL licence which means you can use it in a commercial app).

Comment: Hello i want to create video from images but it take too much time. thank for your reply

Comment: I believe this is another question

Comment: Check out my new question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227569/ffmpeg-images-to-video-take-more-time

Comment: How do we set a video source for `SurfaceView` while using the ffplay command (streaming)?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this FFmpeg sample  which is   library that used without NDK

> **First of download sample example**    [FFmpeg Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qAjo6wKhk9X0E1SkctWHVYTkk/view)
>
> **Download FFmpeg library**  [FFmpeg Library](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qAjo6wKhk9bVBpM0lWYXBSeVk/view)

Extract both in one folder and import project from Android Studio

Now, Calling FFmpeg command

**This command is for rotate (/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4) video in 90 Angle and generate out.mp4 in specific location in SD card**

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vf transpose=1 -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4
```

Now run this command with predefined method in library and add listeners of GeneralUtils

```
GeneralUtils.copyLicenseFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, workFolder);
      GeneralUtils.copyDemoVideoFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, demoVideoFolder);
   //demoVideoFolder where your Input file path
   //workFolder Absolute path
   // workFolder = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";



            LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
        try {
        
            vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext());
            
            // copying vk.log (internal native log) to the videokit folder
            GeneralUtils.copyFileToFolder(vkLogPath, demoVideoFolder);
            
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "vk run exeption.", e);
        }
```

Run this and check in File Manager for Output . I hope it works Good :) Enjoy

Comment: I think its not free library. its allow approx 15 days for trail....so i have just buy it