# FFMpeg : Images to Video take more time

Tags: android, ffmpeg

i am using FFmpeg library project as provided in [This Link](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java).

Actually i want to create video from bunch of images.

i am using following command :

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img%d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

command takes more time to create video. what can i do to improve speed?

Comment: https://github.com/omxcodec/stagefright-plugins

Comment: You need to show the complete console output that appears from your command.