# how to use ffmpeg in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have also tried some demo for FFmpeg but I think it's not a free after some days it's told for licence and give a message licence is expired. can anyone explain step by step process for how to use FFmpeg in android?

Comment: Refer this - https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

Comment: You can also use android-ffmpeg-library ...in order to avoid using ndk.-----https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: @DroidWorm Narendra this is the library project, can you explain any small example with this library or provide any source code for it.

Comment: Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29167496/1479511